# RestAssured and Bearer token

Tags: java, oauth, rest-assured

Very new to RestAssured and authentication in general.

I have an API I can make a get request to in Postman with client credentials. It returns a bearer token.

I am now trying to get this to work with cucumber and restassured.

So very we have this code where it tries to get the bearer token for the next step which is the API call.

```
@Given("^the user has a valid authentication token for credentials$")
public void the_user_with_credentials_something_and_something_has_a_valid_authentication_token() throws Throwable {
    
        RestAssured.baseURI=SCN_CONTEXT.getProp().getExternalUri();
        Response accessTokenResponse = given()
                 .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                 .queryParams("client_id", SCN_CONTEXT.getProp().getClientId())
                 .queryParams("client_secret", SCN_CONTEXT.getProp().getClientSecret())
                 .when().log().all().get(APIResources.valueOf("oAuthAPI").getValue());
         
         System.out.println(accessTokenResponse.getStatusCode());
         SCN_CONTEXT.get_SCN().write("accessTokenResponse: " + accessTokenResponse.getStatusCode());

          JsonPath js=new io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath(accessTokenResponse.body().asString());
            id_token="Bearer " + js.getString("id_token");
            SCN_CONTEXT.setId_token(id_token);
            SCN_CONTEXT._SCN.write("Authentication Token is: " + id_token);
            
    }
```

The externalUri used is the token access uri I have used in Postman.

But on doing this I get a 403 and the token is null

Console log: (anything with ? I removed)

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://?.com/?/v1/?/oauth/token?client_id=?&client_secret=?
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   client_id=?
                client_secret=?
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
403
```

Comment: HTTP 403 is a HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden, Add a `.log().all()` after `given()` and compare the request details from POSTMAN and Rest Assured to check if there are any differences. Also post the complete console logs over here for further debugging

Comment: I obfuscated the client id and secret, where would the best place to find the postman request details? Unsure why the details are not being fetched :S

Comment: lol so that was on purpose was it, so you mean to say in place of `?` you are seeing all the details and yet you are getting a `403` ?

Comment: yes that was on purpose, im seeing the correct details and getting 403

Comment: Can you dial into my WebEx ? If I can take a look at it I can help you resolve it quickly

Comment: sure, how can i do that heh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of things to look at over here, For a similar requirement I had the following in the POSTMAN console. Seemingly this might be a `GET` call but technically this is a `POST` call

The authorization is `Base64` encoded which is sent as a header and the query parameters are `grant_type` and `scope`

The Rest Assured code for this will be

```
given().header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").auth().preemptive()
        .basic("abc", "def")
        .queryParam("grant_type", "client_credentials").queryParam("scope", "123").when()
        .post("ghi").then().extract().response();
```

[image]